# Converting class to non class in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert this code from a class to just the functions without the class. I am thinking `run_quiz` might need an additional parameter but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import random

class Question:
     def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
          self.prompt = prompt
          self.answer = answer

answers = []

question_prompts = [
     "More poeple live in Duluth than in Rochester: t, f, or any to stop",
     "In Harry Potter, Draco Malfoy has no siblings: t, f, or any to stop",
     'The Great Wall of China is longer than the distance between London and Beijing: t, f, or any to stop',
]

questions = [
     Question(question_prompts[0], "t"),
     Question(question_prompts[1], "t"),
     Question(question_prompts[2], "t"),
]

def run_quiz(questions):
     
     for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
               print('correct')
               answers.append(answer)
        elif answer != question.answer and answer == 't' or answer == 'f':
            print('incorrect')
        else: 
            break
            question_prompts.append(answer)
            



run_quiz(questions)
print(answers)
```

Comment: This will flatten into functions really simply.  Just do it.  Take away the class definition and then deal with the individual issues that come up because you did that.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the class? Clearly, a question and an answer is tightly related, so it makes sense to pair them together. Separating them will create a whole bunch of issues in synchronizing them.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman there are ways to preserve that relationship without using a class. At least, without a *new* class. You can keep them bundled in a `tuple`, which drags around far less machinery, and allows for `for q, a in questions` iteration

Comment: @C.Nivs Yes, but tuples are generic holders for generic data. Here we have a very specific relationship with specific data. A class is much better suited for that. And you can easily override the `__iter__` and `__next__` to make it iterable in the same way, although I don't see why that would be any better than just iterating over the instances of the class (`for question in questions`). If you would need to optimize away the small overhead a class (and thus get rid of much flexibility), then it would be better to use a `namedtuple` in that case.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman `namedtuple` would be my vote for this question. Modifying `__next__` and `__iter__` would mean the class would need to be `Questions` rather than `Question`, changing it to be a collection of questions, rather than a single question, and potentially adding additional complexity. I understand where you're coming from, though. There are plenty of cases where some additional methods would be useful, and a class gives you that capability, it just seems a bit heavy for this question IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import random

    
answers = []

def run_quiz(questions):
    score = 0
    for i in range(len(questions)):
        answer = input(questions[i][0])
        if answer == questions[i][1]:
            print('correct')
            answers.append(answer)
        elif answer != questions[i][1] and answer == 't' or answer == 'f':
            print('incorrect')
        else:
            break
                

question_prompts = [
         "More poeple live in Duluth than in Rochester: t, f, or any to stop:-",
         "In Harry Potter, Draco Malfoy has no siblings: t, f, or any to stop:-",
         'The Great Wall of China is longer than the distance between London and Beijing: t, f, or any to stop:-',
]

answers_prompts=["t","t","t"]   
questions = [
         [question_prompts[0], answers_prompts[0]],
         [question_prompts[1], answers_prompts[1]],
         [question_prompts[2], answers_prompts[2]],
]
run_quiz(questions)
```

Edit :

Yes you can get random list by:

> random.shuffle(questions)

The whole code should be like:-

```
import random

    
answers = []

def run_quiz(questions):
    score = 0
    random.shuffle(questions) # Line Chnaged
    for i in range(len(questions)):
        answer = input(questions[i][0])
        if answer == questions[i][1]:
            print('correct')
            answers.append(answer)
        elif answer != questions[i][1] and answer == 't' or answer == 'f':
            print('incorrect')
        else:
            break
                

question_prompts = [
         "More poeple live in Duluth than in Rochester: t, f, or any to stop:-",
         "In Harry Potter, Draco Malfoy has no siblings: t, f, or any to stop:-",
         'The Great Wall of China is longer than the distance between London and Beijing: t, f, or any to stop:-',
]

answers_prompts=["t","t","t"]   
questions = [
         [question_prompts[0], answers_prompts[0]],
         [question_prompts[1], answers_prompts[1]],
         [question_prompts[2], answers_prompts[2]],
]
run_quiz(questions)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the answer_prompts list?

Comment: Also is there a way to select a random question each time and run the program until the user types something other than T or F?

Answer (score 0):

Here's with dictionaries:

```
import random

answers = []

question_prompts = [
        "More poeple live in Duluth than in Rochester: t, f, or any to stop",
        "In Harry Potter, Draco Malfoy has no siblings: t, f, or any to stop",
        'The Great Wall of China is longer than the distance between London and Beijing: t, f, or any to stop',
]

questions = [
    {'question':question_prompts[0],'answer':'t'},
    {'question':question_prompts[1],'answer':'t'},
    {'question':question_prompts[2],'answer':'t'}
]

def run_quiz(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question['question'])
        if answer == question['answer']:
            print('correct')
            score += 1
            answers.append(answer)
        elif answer != question['answer'] and answer == 't' or answer == 'f':
            print('incorrect')
        else:
            question_prompts.append(answer)
            break
            

run_quiz(questions)
print(answers)
```

Comment: Is there any way to select a random question each time and run the program until the user types something other than T or F?